# How to use Stream instead for each loop

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a loop which update an String object:

```
String result = "";
for (SomeObject obj: someObjectList) {
    result = someMetohd(obj, result);
}
```

An implementation of someMethod is irrelevant:

```
private String someMethod(SomeObject obj, String result) {
    result = result.concat(obj.toString());
    return result;
}
```

And I want to use Stream instead a loop. How to implement it with Stream?

Comment: Why do you think a stream-based implementation would be better?

Comment: I want to just know streams

Comment: Then read a [tutorial](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/).

Comment: @Jorn Vernee: doesn’t help here, as `someMethod` is not associative. It would, if the operation was indeed `concat`, but this is only an example…

Answer (score 1):

```
final StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

someObjectList.stream().map(SomeObject::toString).forEach(resultBuilder::append);

final String result = resultBuilder.toString();
```

To know more about Streams, you can check this page: http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/, I think it's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
@SuppressWarnings("OptionalGetWithoutIsPresent")
String result = Stream.concat(Stream.of(""), someObjectList.stream())
        .reduce(this::someMethod)
        .get();
```

- Your `someMethod` should be associative as specified in the documentation, however this is only important for parallel streams, while your code is explicitly sequential
- As you always add to the `result`, you can consider it a first element of the stream and then use `reduce` method which will always merge first two elements - current result and next element
- `result` has to be the first parameter of your `someMethod`
- Because all elements in the stream have to be of the same type, while you have `String result` and `SomeObject` elements, you need to change the signature of `someMethod` to accept two `Object`s (and do the casts inside the method): `private String someMethod(Object result, Object obj)`. This is the most ugly part of this solution.
- You can inline the initial value of the result - no need to define `result` upfront
- You might want to change `this::someMethod` depending on where this method is declared
- Finally, you don't need to worry about handling `Optional` result, because the stream always has at least one element so it's safe to just call `get()`

Answer (score 1):

Although the *functional equivalent* of what you're trying to achieve here is possible with streams, it's worth reminding you that functional and iterative ways of thinking are not necessarily compatible.

Generally you think of each element on its own, and you don't have visibility over other elements, unless you're using a special function like reduce.

Here's something that does what you've asked for:

```
  final List<Object> objectList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");

  String concatString = objectList.stream()
            .map(e -> e.toString())
            .reduce((result, element) -> result.concat(e))
            .get();
```

Map turns the entire stream into a list, but with the toString function called separately on every element. Reduce is more complex. It can be described as an accumulation. It executes a function between the result, and the current element. In this case, it takes the first element, and concatenates it to the second. It then takes the first/second concatenation, and applies the same function to the third. And so on.

Instead of dealing with lambdas, you can also pass in methods directly, to tighten up your code a bit:

```
String result = objectList.stream()
                    .map(Object::toString)
                    .reduce(String::concat)
                    .get();
```